# Read bytes from a binary file, turn a few of them into ints in C

Tags: arrays

Let's say I have a binary file containing this:

`0b 10 00 00 06 00 00 1a  66 32 2e 74 78 74 70 6f 
72 ....`

I used hexdump -C file to get these values.

How can I read the first eight bytes and put them into an array and turn them into ints? In the end I want to have an int mybytes[8] which contains:

```
mybytes[0] = 11 
mybytes[1] = 16
.....
mybytes[4] = 6
.....
mybytes[7] = 26.
```

I tried reading those eight bytes using:

```
unsigned char mybytes[8];
fread(mybytes, 8, 1, myfile);
```

And I can even print out the values I need like this:

```
for (k=0; k<4; k++)
printf("%d\n", mybytes[k]);
```

but I need to actually use those values. I don't understand how chars really work so I am a little confused here. I was thinking about writing all of them in a temporary text file and reading them later as ints... but I am sure there must be better methods out there.

Also, but not necessary. Is it possible to read four bytes at a time and find their decimal value? For example reading `0b 10 00 00` as a whole and having the value of 4107? I know how to calculate them if I have those four values separately in an array  (whether in hex or decimal and yes I am aware of the fact that the whole number in hex would be 0000100b), but I am wondering if there is a faster way to do it.

Comment: Do you know how large (how many bytes) an `int` is in this case in the file? Do you know the "endianness" of the data in the file?

Comment: @lurker it should be 4 bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the file is in native endianness it should not be necessary to use a byte array at all, just do this:

```
int foo;
fread(&foo, sizeof(int), 1, myfile);
printf("%d", foo);
```

it will write directly into the int.
By virtue of fread's ability to read multiple objects at once it is also possible to fill a whole array of ints at once with the following code (this usage of fread courtesy of @lurker):

```
int N = 4; // Change this to the number of ints in the file
int foo[N];
fread(data, sizeof(int), N, myfile);
for(int iter = 0; iter < N iter++)
{
    printf("%d", foo[iter]);
}
```

Comment: @lurker Yup, I mentioned that in the first line. But that is a good point, byte swapping is a whole other matter though the header byteswap.h is useful there.

Comment: @Ssurge Glad I could help, if you have any other issues please feel free to comment and I will try and edit my post to include them.

Comment: This even answers my second question. I can always read 4 bytes at a time and have them automatically converted into the int value I need.

Comment: @Vality got it, sorry, I'm going blind... :p

Comment: @lurker No worries, if someone else made this answer I would probably have made the same comment. :)

Comment: It may be worth noting (again, endianness being favorable) that an entire array of integers could be read this way (`int data[N];` and `fread(data, N, sizeof(int), myfile);` or something like that).

Comment: @lurker Is it ok if I put that into the answer?

Comment: @Ssurge Sorry if this sounds presumptuous but if this solved your issue please consider accepting so others know you have solved the issue.

Comment: @Vality you bet. :) Technically, I should have said, `fread(data, sizeof(int), N, myfile);` :)